# Laravel PHP получить минимальное значение

Tags: php

Имеется string такого вида

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(108) "Айти|501.64|Small|412.77|Лик|515.00" }
```

Как из этого поля получить минимальное значение, то есть 412.77?

Comment: Метки поправьте... В вопроса Laravel - в метках нет.. Вам нужен чистый php?

Comment: Да чистый php тоже подойдет :)

Comment: Ну тогда ищите в сторону `explode('|', $array);`, а потом `sort($array);` и берете верхний элемент

Answer (score 1):

Такой вариант подойдет?

```
$str = "Айти|501.64|Small|412.77|Лик|515.00";
echo min(explode("|", $str));
```

Ну для вашего примера в одну строчку

```
echo min(explode("|", $array[0]));
```

### UPDATE

Как оказалось, автору нужна пара - имя<>цифра

Тогда решение предлагаю такое:

```
preg_match_all('/(.*?)?\|([\d\.]+)?/', $array[0], $m, PREG_SET_ORDER);
$t = Array();
foreach($m as $pair) {
    if (Count($pair)<=2) continue;
    $t[$pair[1]] = $pair[2];
}
asort($t);
echo "Min value: " . current($t) . "<br />";
echo "Min name: " . key($t) . "<br />";
```

- С помощью `regex` выдергиваем пары.
- Переделываем из в ассоциативный массив
- сортируем массив по значениям
- берем первое значение и первый ключ

У этого решения есть недостаток: может работать некорректно, если есть повторящиеся имена.

Comment: спасибо все работает :)

Comment: А можно результат сдвинуть на -1 позицию влево?

Comment: Рад. @ОнотолЕ, если ответ Вас устраивает - его надо пометить как "отвеченный" (зеленая галочка около стрелочек). Это закроет вопрос, и увеличит статистику сообщества.

Comment: Не понял, что значит "позицию влево". Например? Сейчас вам вернется 412.77. Что Вы хотите получить?

Comment: 412.77 ----- Small

Comment: Вот такой ответ хочу получить)

Comment: Аааааааааа, так Вам пара нужна... тогда совсем другое дело. Тогда вообще решение должно быть иное...

Comment: Подскажите как получить? :)

Comment: ответ обновлен.

Answer (score 0):

Можно же совсем просто

```
$str = "Айти|501.64|Small|412.77|Лик|515.00";
$m= explode('|', $str);
$min=1;
for($t=1; $t<count($m); $t+=2) if($m[$t] > $m[$min]) $min=$t;

print_r($m[min-1]);
```